# The metric space and the balls.

Tags: metric-spaces

> Let $M$ be a metric space with a distance function $d$, and let
>   $a,b,c\in M$ be given. Let $r,s,t>0$ and assume that $c\in K(b,s):=\lbrace x\in M\mid d(b,x)<s\rbrace$.
>
> a) Show that if $d(a,b)\leq r-s-t$, then $K(c,t)\subseteq K(a,r)$.
>
> b) Show that if $d(a,b)\geq r+s+t$, then $K(c,t)\cap K(a,r)=\emptyset$.

Here's what the lemma sounds like,

> **Lemma 1:** i) If $b\in K(a,r)$ and $0<s\leq r-d(a,b)$, then $K(b,s)\subseteq K(a,r)$.
>
> ii) If $K(a,r)\cap K(b,s)\neq \emptyset$, then $d(a,b)<r+s$.

**My anwers** a) Assume that $m\in K(c,t)$. I want to show that $d(a,m)<r$. Since $c\in K(b,s)$ is assumed, so we have 
\begin{equation*}
d(a,c)\leq d(a,b)+d(b,c)<d(a,b)+s.
\end{equation*}
Then we have
\begin{equation*}
d(a,m)\leq d(a,c)+d(c,m)< (d(a,b)+s)+t\leq r.
\end{equation*}
This indicates that $c\in K(a,r)$ and hence $K(c,t)\subseteq K(a,r)$ by Lemma 1.

b) I have tried to prove it by contraposition, but I have no idea how to manage it. If
\begin{align*}
\neg(K(c,t)\cap K(a,r)=\emptyset)&\implies \neg(d(a,b)\geq r+s+t)\iff\\
(K(c,t)\cup K(a,r)\neq \emptyset)&\implies (d(a,b)< r+s+t)
\end{align*}
is correct I need a hand to continue proving it.

Here is a picture how I imagined the figure looks like[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (b) just observe that if $\exists p\in K(c,t)\cap K(a,r)$, then, $$d(a,b)\le d(a,p)+d(p,c)+d(c,b)<r+t+s$$ which gives the required contradiction.

Comment: I am sorry, I really don't get it. Could you please elaborate it? How is it a contradiction and why? What do you think about my answer for part (a)? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your answer for part (a) is fine. For part (b) I have assumed that let's say $K(c,t)\cap K(a,r)\ne \emptyset$. Then we can find a point $p\in K(c,t)\cap K(a,r)$. But that would imply that distance between $a,b$ will be less than $r+t+s$ which contradicts the hypothesis in the question.